# TFS 2013 build does not deploy ASP.NET web application

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy

I have a new TFS 2013 instance with its own build server that compiles a solution and deploys a database project without error. I added an MS build activity for deploying the web application projects in the solution to a target server, and that activity appears to execute without error, but nothing is actually published in the target.

Running the same publish profile from within Visual Studio on my local machine works properly. I dont know if it is missing some dependency (Web deploy 3.5 is installed on both the build and target servers, I am reinstalling VS 2013 on the build server).

Are there any specific steps/prerequisites required to make this work correctly on a TFS 2013 build server? I cannot find anything on the web other than "Install VS and MSDeploy".

I have this all working properly on a 2010 build server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing and enabling diagnostic level logging, I found that the build activity was trying to use VS 2012 (version 11) activity targets for these VS 2013 (version 12) projects. (VS 2010, 2012, and 2013 have been installed on this server to support various build activities)

In the activity specific log file this looks like this...

```
CodeAnalysisTargets = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets
```

This was causing the build process to log...

```
_DeploymentUnpublishable
  Skipping unpublishable project
```

...and skip the publishing.

To fix this, I set the ToolVersion property of the MSBuild activity to "12.0" and re-ran the build